# How to source an external file in .bash_profile in OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, bash

I have defined some aliases in my `.bash_profile` file and aliases work as expected. e.g

```
alias python-server="python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7070"
```

And, When I open new terminal, typing `python-server` opens up a python server with current directory as root (or "/").

But I have around 10 aliases and I want to backup the aliases So I thought to create an external file which contain these aliases and am trying to source that file from .bash_profile like this

```
source ~/personal/Dropbox/scripts/aliases.sh
```

But when I open the new terminal I receive the errors

```
Last login: Fri Dec 11 23:16:28 on ttys004
: No such file or directory
: command not found
: command not found
```

However, my commands are working fine. e.g. `python-server` works as expected from external file. I just want to know the reason of this error and may be a better way to achieve this.

#### Contents of .bash_profile

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

# Load aliases
source ~/personal/repo/scripts/aliases

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/personal/repo/scripts/commands
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/personal/repo/scripts/git
export PATH
```

#### Contents of alias file

```
#!/bin/bash

# ---------------
# Load my aliases
# ---------------
alias python-server="python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7070"
```

PS: Now, I removed the comment from aliases file and it reduced the count of `: command not found` from `2` to `1` when opening a new terminal.

Comment: @Mods should this question be moved to Unix StackExchange site ?

Comment: When you try to run it manually it works well? (Exactly what's written in the `.bash_profile`)

Comment: @Yaron Yes, commands are working fine when run manually. But I see the log as mentioned above when I open a new terminal everytime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove 'control codes', i.e. '\r' from your files above.

How to check:

```
  cat ~/.bashprofile  | od -c ## see any '\r's?
```

Use 'vi' or 'vim' to edit the files or 'clean' using 'tr', i.e.

```
tr -d '\r' ~/.bashprofile > ~/.bashprofile.mod  
cp ~/.bashprofile.mod ~/.bashprofile
```

Comment: Thanks @Dale for providing me some hint. Actually, I created the file in sublime text on Mac which added control codes. I copied the content of file line by line since there were two lines and pasted them into a new file inside vim. Later deleted the original file and renamed the new file worked for me. Your tr command was giving an error BTW.

Comment: Error: `tr: extra operand aliases.sh
Only one string may be given when deleting without squeezing repeats.` Please fix this so I can accept

Comment: I..e == 'for example'; it does NOT imply an absolute answer; No way for me to 'fix' since I do NOT use a MAC (and works fine on my Linux system...);  either my answer was helpful or not; the business of absolute answers for NON-abosolute problems/issues is balderdash; I don't really care if you accept for not - just acknowledge that your issue is resolved (perhaps others will get to solutions faster) and we all move forward.... :)

Comment: I also tried the same command on ubuntu 12.10 64 bit and It gave me the error. Yes, your suggestion **helped me fix the problem** but I think there is something missing in your example. Thanks anways!!

Comment: It is not about you care or not for answer acceptance but it is for future readers because they may be trying the same thing and getting answer. Anyways, I have accepted considering your i..e is just a direction and not exact command