# How to source an external file in .bash_profile macOS

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, alias

I tried to move my script from linux to mac, folder ~/Scripts placed in home with all other scripts,
but using source in `.bash_profile` won't call my script.

#### Contents of .bash_profile

```
f [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
    . ~/Scripts/ipmitool
fi

alias test='echo test from bash_profile'
```

#### Contents of /Scripts/ipmitool

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]] ; then
    printf "ipmitool <Host IP> \n\n"
else
    ssh con_1 ipmitool -I lanplus -U * -P * -H  $1 fru print
fi
```

#### Terminal

```
1232324fa:~ OiO$ ipmitool
-bash: ipmitool: command not found

1232324fa:~ OiO$ bash ~/Scripts/ipmitool
ipmitool <Host IP>
```

I need to use `bash` in front to be able to call ipmitool, in linux I just need to type ipmitool.

I tried to follow this [How to source an external file in .bash_profile in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235425/how-to-source-an-external-file-in-bash-profile-in-osx) but didn't work.

Could someone help this newb, Thanks.

Comment: I guess the lone `f` in your .bash_profile is supposed to be `if`.  Do a `set -x; . ~/.bash_profle` to debug it. How did you verify, that your `.bash_profile` was beeing sourced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you want to source it. You want to add `~/Scripts` to your path, so that later you can type `ipmitool` rather than `~/Scripts/ipmitool` to execute it.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=~/Scripts:$PATH

alias test='echo test from bash_profile'
```

(Make sure `~/Scripts/ipmitool` is executable, as well, by running

```
chmod +x ~/Scripts/ipmitool
```

)

Comment: sorry for my foolish question, I missed that part of script to paste because my lack of understanding between path and source. could you give me an easy explaination what is the difference between source and path? Thank you very much.

Comment: `PATH` just tells the shell where to look for a command if you try to run it by name only. Sourcing actually executes the content of the file *immediately* in the current shell process.